# PHP SoapClient does not match type if restriction is given

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

i have a problem with the PHP SoapClient. The objects generated by the client don't have all the attributes they should.

In my case 2 Elements (description, description2) have the same complex type (Text). One of them has a restriction (description). In the resulting PHP object the attribut "language" is missing.

Example from the WSDL:

```
<xs:complexType name="Text">
  <xs:simpleContent>
     <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="language" type="string"/>
     </xs:extension>
  </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" name="description">
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:restriction base="tns:Text">
            <xs:maxLength value="400"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="description2" type="tns:Text">
<xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation>...</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
```

Objects in PHP

```
public 'description' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            object(stdClass)[6]
              public '_' => string 'some string' (length=17)
public 'description2' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            object(stdClass)[7]
              public '_' => string 'some other string' (length=1796)
              public 'language' => string 'de_DE' (length=5)
```

WSDL is valid.
I cannot change the WSDL.
A typemap for the SoapClient has no effect because the type does not match for description.

How do i receive the language attribute in description?